# How mvc model how which table to store

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm create an mvc website to save the data to the database,
but its can not save the data to the database.

Here is my web form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            <fieldset>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tname)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tname)



                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.phone)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.icno)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.icno)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gender)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gender)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cate)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cate)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.hname)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hname)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.htype)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.htype)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.hfrom)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hfrom)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.hto)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hto)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.hcost)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hcost)
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="res" id="b1" disabled onclick="confirm('Sure?')" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
```

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult reservehotel(Reserve p)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (_db)
            {
                _db.hinfo.Add(p);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                ModelState.Clear();
                p = null;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }

        return View(p);
    }
```

The controller have run the Redirect

Here is my modal

```
public class Reserve
{
    [Key]
    public int resID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string tname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string icno { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string gender { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string cate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string hname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string htype { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string hfrom { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string hto { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string hcost { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my db

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Reserve> hinfo { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my Table

```
 **CREATE TABLE [dbo].[hinfo] (
    [Id]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [tname]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [phone]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [icno]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [gender] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [cate]   NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [hname]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [htype]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [hfrom]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [hto]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [hcost]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);**
```

I have some question to ask

1) Why I can not store the data to the database but I can read the data from database?

2) Is any miss taken in my code?

3)  How the modals know which table to store?

Comment: Have you got any exception error?

Comment: it is working there are no issue but . what is your view page name ?

Comment: My view page name is same as controller reservehotel.cshtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your third question, the following line:

`public DbSet<Reserve> hinfo { get; set; }`

creates a DbSet property for the Reserve entity. In Entity Framework terminology, an entity set typically corresponds to a database table, and an entity corresponds to a row in the table.

Comment: This is correct answer! I get it by change the Reserve to the table name

Answer (score 0):

Reserve is you db table? if it is your table then you have to get data to store in it in controller like in custom php we get data $_POST[name]

Comment: $reserve=new $Reserve();
$reserve->tname=$p->name;
$reserve->save(); i tried it in Laravel MVC framework its worked in it

Comment: My table is hinfo so means that the table name must same which modal calss name?

Comment: yes i must be same i think which u specify in entity framework